# Datorama - How can I cross-reference third-party sales data imported into Marketing Cloud with email opens for a comprehensive campaign outcome graph?

Tags: marketing-cloud, conversion, datorama, sfmc-datorama

I'm working on a marketing campaign within Salesforce Marketing Cloud, and I've successfully imported sales data from a third-party system. Now, I'm looking for a way to cross-reference this data with email opens to obtain a comprehensive view of the campaign outcome, focusing particularly on conversions.

I'm wondering if anyone has experiences or advice on how I can achieve this integration and present the data in a meaningful graph. Are there specific tools within Marketing Cloud or best practices for tackling this type of analysis?

Comment: can I know why after 1 day, this question has been downvoted?

Answer (score -5):

From the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_tracking.htm&type=5):

> Single-send objects, such as Lead, Contact, and Person Account
> records, provide tracking information about individual records.
> Navigate to a specific lead, contact, or person account to view
> tracking for a single send. Two related lists provide detailed
> information about Individual Email Results and Email Sends for that
> specific record. The Email Sends tab provides a record of each email
> send with tracking information. The Send Analytics tab provides
> reports on historical and time-based engagement for aggregate, email,
> or subscriber data.

Comment: Copied from Salesforce documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_tracking.htm&type=5).

Comment: yes in marketing cloud cross cloud products subpoint Tracking and Analytics

Comment: Downvoted for plagiarism. If you reference someone else's work, you need to give them credit for it. Failing to do that is an attempt to claim someone else's work as your own.

Comment: it's not related to datorama